# Getting the URI of a Bitmap Variable

Tags: java, android, bitmap, fresco

I want to know if it's possible to get the URI of a bitmap variable(I want to use it with a Fresco SimpleDraweeView).
If not what alternative should I use?

Comment: No, it is not possible.  Variables don't have URIs.  Furthermore, while a `Bitmap` can be created from something that your app reads from a URI, the URI is not stored in the `Bitmap` object ... and cannot be retrieved from it.

Comment: You could save the `Bitmap` into a file on the device, and then get the URI for for the file ...

Comment: It might do the job but it will not be suitable for my case.

Comment: Maybe you should be using `DraweeView` instead.  It looks like you can create one and then set a bitmap.  Check the javadocs.